# Deny direct access to files but allow query strings in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I browsed through all the htaccess solutions but none are good for my scenario...

Basically I want to deny direct access to all file types except the ones listed, like this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|less|pdf|php|html)$">
Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```

The problem is I can't use urls like /?foo=bar but must use /index.php?foo=bar ...

How to solve this? RewriteCond? Can anyone drop a oneliner that does the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|less|pdf|php|html|htm)$">
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Escape the leading `.` as well!